# Java, Swing: tooltip and affine transformation issue

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, affinetransform

Writing GUI in Java, an interesting problem has appeared. I apologize for a slightly longer code.

There is class Graphic derived from JPanel which displays uploaded raster. It implements several features with the raster data including the zoom operations. It also supports a mouse click event which stores coordinates of a point and displays it over the raster. The raster is fitted with the affine transformation.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.geom.*;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class Graphic extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image; 
    private AffineTransform trans;
    Point2D.Double point;

    public Graphic () {
            try {image = ImageIO.read(new File("e:/Work/test.jpg"));}
            catch (Exception e) {}
            trans = new AffineTransform();
            trans.translate(0, 0);
            trans.scale(1, 1);
            point = new Point2D.Double(0,0);
            this.setToolTipText("");

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            point.x = (e.getPoint().getX() - trans.getTranslateX()) / trans.getScaleX();
                            point.y = (e.getPoint().getY() - trans.getTranslateY()) / trans.getScaleY();
                            System.out.println(trans);  //Print affine transformation parameters
                            System.out.println(e.getPoint().getX() + " " + e.getPoint().getY()); //Cursor coordinates
                            repaint();
                    } 
            });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            if (image != null ){    
                    trans = g2d.getTransform();
                    Dimension size = this.getVisibleRect().getSize();
                    double sx = (size.getWidth() - image.getWidth()) / 2;
                    double sy = (size.getHeight() - image.getHeight()) / 2;
                    trans.translate(sx, sy);
                    g2d.setTransform(trans);
                    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);        
                    g2d.fillOval((int)point.x - 10, (int)point.y - 10,  20,  20);
                    g2d.dispose();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) { 
            double x = (e.getX() - trans.getTranslateX()) / trans.getScaleX();
            double y = (e.getY() - trans.getTranslateY()) / trans.getScaleY();
            return String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%2.2f", x) + "  " + String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%3.2f", y); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(800, 600);
            f.add(new Graphic());
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

The class redefines the tool tip method and displays coordinates of the cursor.

Before a tool tip appears the mouse click into the picture works as expected

[Figure1: mouse click, without tool tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Mv5.jpg)

a circle appears at the right location.

[Figure 2: drawn point mark, without tool tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlMyQ.jpg)

Subsequently, let us repeat theses steps after a tool tip appears. The mouse click at the picture

[Figure 3: mouse click, tool tip appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxiBV.jpg)

behaves unexpectedly, and the point is drawn far away.

[Figure4: drawn point mark, tool tip appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8YhM.jpg)

Debugging the code, the following problem has has been found... When a tool tip appears, the shift ratios sx=mo2, sy=m12 in the affine transformation change from

```
AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, -1927.5], [0.0, 1.0, -1435.1]]
379.0 339.0  //Cursor coordinates xc, yc
```

to

```
AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, -2303.5], [0.0, 1.0, -1794.5]]
376.0 339.0  //Cursor coordinates xc, yc
```

To avoid a shift of the entire situation, instead m02 and m12 shifts, the transformed coordinates point.x, point.y should be corrected adding cursor coordinates + something. Is it a bug in the Swing library or a feature :-) ?

Thanks for very much for your comments, help or explanation...

The raster file: [test.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgk7p.jpg).

Comment: *"The remaining code is.."*  For better help sooner, post ***one*** [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) rather than a bunch of uncompilable code snippets. One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to the images embedded in this question.

Comment: I dont care about the tooltip you have a trans which is used throughout and change whenever it pleases you - now is this a bug or a feature??

Comment: @ Andrew: Due to the complexity, I am not able to make a shorter code. The code was updated and it is compilable. It works poor for any uploaded JPG file.

Comment: *"I am not able to make a shorter code."* Are you able to develop a longer attention span? There is more to an MCVE/SSCCE than either the initial M or S, note that if it is all truly needed to be CVE/SCCE, the code can run up to 200 LOC and still fit the description. Now copy the `main(String[])` method back into the end of the `Graphic` class, ***change*** the `File` to an `URL` pointing to the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHgX1.jpg) then copy/paste the entire (including imports) result into a new project in your IDE and **check** it compiles cleanly and displays the problem!

Comment: @ Andrew: Thanks for your recommendations. I hope that the post is clearer and more readable...

Comment: Your code seems to work correctly for me  `AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, -2491.5], [0.0, 1.0, -1712.5]]`
 `347.0 118.0`
 `AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, -2491.5], [0.0, 1.0, -1712.5]]` 
`345.0 119.0` with or without tooltip. I don't see the problem that the circle is in another location

Comment: @ bhavya.work: that is strange. I checked the results, the problem still exists: NetBeans 8.2, Win 10, 64bit, JDK 1.8

Comment: 1) Firstly note that by putting a space between the `@` symbol in comments, and the name of the person, we are not getting notified! 2) Which freakin' part of *"One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to the images embedded in this question."* & *"**change** the `File` to an `URL` pointing to the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHgX1.jpg]"* do you ***not*** understand?!? I don't have the time or patience to mention things a 3rd, 4th or 5th time. If there is anything I write that you do not understand, say so! But stop ignoring suggestions - I don't write them for my sake.

Comment: @Andrew I appreciate you effort to achieve arrangement and formal rules of posts; the necessary condition to maintain readability and clarity of discussions... Please, avoid using too many acronyms in your posts. The following sentence " There is more to an MCVE/SSCCE than either the initial M or S, note that if it is all truly needed to be CVE/SCCE, the code can run up to 200 LOC and still fit the description."  almost does not make sense :-) What may seem like ignorance may be misunderstanding your comments....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly simple...

It is necessary to call another repaint() before coordinates of a point are stored. Therefore, the mouse press event foregoing the mouse click event is utilized:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    repaint();
}
```